# pass selected option value from select to php

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
    <style type="text/css">
    form select {
        display:none;
    }
    form select.active {
        display:block;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var allElem = document.getElementsByName("sl");
        for (i = 0; i < allElem.length; i++) {
            allElem[i].addEventListener('change', toggleDisplay);
        }
   }
    function toggleDisplay(e) {
       var id = 's' + this.value;
        var currentSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
        if (currentSelect) {
            currentSelect.className = "";
        }
        document.getElementById(id).className = "active";
    }    
    </script>
    </head><body>
    <form action="check_a.php">
    <h2><b>Source: </b></h2>
    <input type="radio" name="sl"  value="c">Central</input>
    <input type="radio" name="sl"  value="h">Eastern</input>
    <input type="radio" name="sl" value="w">Western</input>

    <select id="sc" name="sc">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="sh">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>

    <select id="sw">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

    </form></body></html>
```

there is one radio button whose value displays the specific select box, which is done using javascript.
the value of  tag needs to be passed to php code. 
How can i pass the selected option value to php?

Comment: The above code will pass the selected options to PHP when the form is submitted. What particular issue are you having?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can't you just set all the `select` elements to have the same name?

```
<select id="sc" name="tagvalue">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="sh" name='tagvalue'>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="sw" name='tagvalue'>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

Then, just take the value of `$_POST['tagvalue']`.

Comment: i tried giving the same name for all select tags, but option value of only one select tag got send to the php file , even on changing the options of the radio buttons.

Comment: It is never necessary to duplicate your option text as the option's `value` attribute.  Just omit that bit of markup bloat.